# Fatal error: Call to undefined function null2unknown()

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Hi i am using some other's code in my website . that's to payment gateway integration . why this error is coming ? i am new to php please help . example code is

```
$amount          = null2unknown($_GET["vpc_Amount"]);
$locale          = null2unknown($_GET["vpc_Locale"]);
```

error is : Fatal error: Call to undefined function null2unknown()

Comment: You don't have the function `null2unknown`.

Comment: https://github.com/morrislaptop/payments/blob/master/models/behaviors/migs.php

Comment: you mean i can use that code in my website ?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is very old question, I stumbled upon it when searching for the function.

It seems that your application doesnt include the function below:

```
function null2unknown($map, $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $map)) {
        if (!is_null($map[$key])) {
            return $map[$key];
       }
    } 
    return "No Value Returned";
 }
```

This is a common function seen when implementing MiGS gateways.